# continuous deployment of a grails app

Tags: grails, jetty, jenkins, war

I am working on a grails app and need regularly to deploy hot fixes to a remote server. I am using jenkins with grails plugin for automation.

My point is the following:

Most of the time i fix a few classes, with no big changes in the app (such as new database schema, new plugins....). However each time i create a patch i have to upload trough ssh a 75M war file, which takes between 15 to 20 min. Most of the data is not needed (ie all the packaged jars). What would be sufficient is to upload only the fresh compiled classes from `WEB-INF/classes/` and reload the servlet container (in my case jetty).

Anybody experienced with this, preferably with jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember seeing this subject on the mailing list...

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Incremental-Deployment-td3066617.html

...they recommend using rsync or xdelta3 to only transfer updated files. Haven't tried it, but it might help you?

Answer (score 2):

Check the *nojars* argument for the *war* task: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/war.html

This way you can place all your .jars (which are usually the biggest files inside a .war) in some other directory on the server and just reference that directory in your Jetty classpath.

---

Or you could write a shell script to explode the .war file (after all it's just a regular .zip file), add the compiled classes and then re-package it.

Comment: That is a good idea, but i may enter a dependency hell since there are few servlets running on the instance, right?

Comment: interesting, so far, I think about a combination of your suggestions: war --nojars + upload over shh + unpack classes and copy and redeploy somehow, without erasing the changes. But i would rather go for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/) to do continuous delivery releases. They also use deltas to upload your changes, and deployments don't affect the user experience at all.

An easy to use plugin is available to make the process seamless from within your Grails app and in a Jenkins build. I've written a [blog post](http://mycodesnippets.com/2011/05/11/continuous-delivery-with-grails-on-cloudbees/) about how to get it all working easily.

Comment: Thanks Marco, already read your post few days ago :) but requirements is to deploy on client server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Cloudfoundry Micro Cloud](https://www.cloudfoundry.com/micro) is an option, a deployment just transfers the deltas and not the whole war file.

Comment: actually that is good as well, but i would like to have it without cloud foundry micro cloud. I'll have a look to the source to see how it works (i think tomcat or tcserver is the servlet container)